# Lots of text files into one big text file

Tags: files, cat

I want to combine thousands of little text files into one big text file. I have them in directories with the structure: `timestamp1/status.txt`. For example: `20130430133144/status.txt`.
So far, I know that

```
cat */* > bigtextfile.txt
```

works for small numbers of files. But will it work for higher numbers? I wonder if `cat` is going to gather the content of all files and then try to save to the `bigtextfile`. Otherwise, I suppose there must another way to do it, like fetch one file, append it to `bigtextfile`, then fetch another and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No `cat` will not buffer all the files before it starts writing out.

However if you have a large number of files you can run into an issue with the number of arguments passed to `cat`. By default the linux kernel only allows a fixed number of arguments to be passed to any program (I can't remember how to get the value, but its a few thousand in most cases).
To solve this issue you can do something like this instead:

```
find -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec cat {} \; > bigtextfile.txt
```

This will basically call `cat` separately for each and every file found by `find`.

Answer (score 10):

In:

```
cat */* > bigtextfile.txt
```

The shell will expand `*/*` into the sorted list of (non-hidden) matching files, and will execute `cat` with those file paths as arguments.

`cat` will open each file in turn and write on its stdout what it reads from the file. `cat` will not hold more than one buffer full of data (something like a few kilo bytes) at a time in memory.

A problem you may encounter though is that the list of arguments to `cat` is so big  that it reaches the limit of the size of arguments of the `execve()` system call. So, you may need to split that list of files and run `cat` several times.

You could use `xargs` for that (here with GNU or BSD `xargs` for the non-standard `-r` and `-0` options):

```
printf '%s\0' */* | xargs -r0 cat -- > big-file.txt
```

(because `printf` is built in the shell, it doesn't go through the `execve` system call, so not through its limit).

Or have `find` make the list of files and run as many cat commands as necessary:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec cat {} + > big-file.txt
```

Or portably:

```
find . -path './*/*' -prune -type f -exec cat {} + > big-file.txt
```

(beware though that contrary to `*/*`, it will include hidden files (and files in hidden directories), not look for files in symlinks to directories, and the list of files will not be sorted).

If on a recent version of Linux, you can lift the limit on the size of arguments by doing:

```
ulimit -s unlimited
cat -- */* > big-file.txt
```

With `zsh`, you could also use `zargs`:

```
autoload zargs
zargs -- */* -- cat > big-file.txt
```

With `ksh93`, you can use `command -x`:

```
command -x cat -- */* > big-file.txt
```

All those do the same thing, split the list of files and run as many `cat` commands as necessary.

With `ksh93` again, you can get around the `execve()` limit by using the builtin `cat` command:

```
command /opt/ast/bin/cat -- */* > big-file.txt
```

Comment: IIRC, the ability to use `+` on the `-exec` of `find` is limited to GNU find.

Comment: @Patrick. No, that's the other way round. `+` is standard, and GNU `find` was one of the last ones to support it (in 2005).

Answer (score 1):

If the number of files is too large, the `*/*` will give a too large argument list. If so, something along the lines will do:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs cat > outfile
```

(the idea is to use `find` to pick up the file names, and make them into a stream; `xargs` chops this stream up into manageable pieces to give to `cat`, which concatenes them into the output stream of `xargs`, and that goes into `outfile`).

Comment: However not that that assumes none of the file names contain SPC, TAB, Newline, single quote, double quote or backslash characters.